# Python - Discrete deconvolution using Toeplitz matrix

Tags: python, deconvolution, matrix, linear-algebra

Lets say I have 2 vectors (1D signals that are sigmoids): $s$ and $m$, both related through the relation: $m = s * r$, my goal here is to recover the vector $r$ (should be a gaussian $\rightarrow$ gives the $m$ sigmoid a smoother/steeper slope depending on $\sigma$).

I tried to use Fourier transforms but it did not work very well (see here: [https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/88801/convolution-and-fourier-transform-for-1d-signals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci2SZ.png)), then tried to use `deconvolve` from scipy but once again I do not get the right gaussian.

Then someone told me on my last post to look into Toeplitz matrices knowing the following relationship (discrete convolution):
$$ m[n] = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} s[n-k] r[k]$$
we then have n equations with $k$ parameters $\rightarrow$ matrix problem to solve.
You'll find below my code using this post: [Matlab - Toeplitz matrices](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15096/relationship-between-discrete-deconvolution-and-toeplitz-matrices).
But now I have a problem with my python code as the output does not give a proper gaussian, and if I i fit the peak that looks like one I always get a 2/3 ratio of difference for the standard deviation between the 'real' gaussian used for the convolution and the one I get through this process (see the plots I give both $\sigma$), how could I explain this ?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def sigmoid(x, A, x0, k):
    return A / (1 + np.exp(k * (x - x0)))

def gaussian(x, mu, sigma):
    return np.exp(-((x - mu) ** 2) / (2 * sigma ** 2))

x = np.arange(0., 20.01, 0.01)

# Create a Gaussian signal
mu_gaussian = 10.0
sigma_gaussian = 1.0
y = gaussian(x, mu_gaussian, sigma_gaussian)

# Create a sigmoid-like filter
A_sigmoid = 1.0
x0_sigmoid = 10.0
k_sigmoid = -3.0
sigmo = sigmoid(x, A_sigmoid, x0_sigmoid, k_sigmoid)

sigmo2 = sigmoid(x, A_sigmoid, x0_sigmoid, -0.5)

plt.plot(sigmo, label = '1st sigmo')
plt.plot(sigmo2, label = 'convolved sigmo')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
# yc = scipy.signal.convolve(y, c, mode='full') / c.sum()
# ydc, remainder = scipy.signal.deconvolve(yc, c)
M = len(sigmo2)

# Create the first row of the Toeplitz matrix using the sigmoid values
first_row = np.concatenate((sigmo, np.zeros(M - 1)))
# Create the first column of the Toeplitz matrix with zeros and the first element of `sigmo`
first_col = np.concatenate(([sigmo[0]], np.zeros(M - 1)))

# Generate the Toeplitz matrix
A = scipy.linalg.toeplitz(first_col, first_row)

# # Calculate the product of transpose(A) and A
# product = np.dot(A.transpose(), A)
# # Calculate the inverse of the matrix product
# inverse_product = np.linalg.inv(product)
# # We get the moore penrose pseudo inverse
# Penrose = np.dot(inverse_product, A.transpose())

Penrose = np.linalg.pinv(A)
#Finally our retrieved gaussian
gauss_toep = np.dot(Penrose, sigmo_conv)

# Create new x values matching the length of gauss_toep
x_fit = np.linspace(0, 20, len(gauss_toep))

plt.plot(x_fit, gauss_toep)
plt.show()

popt_gauss, _ = curve_fit(gaussian, x_fit, gauss_toep, p0=[0.0001, 0.001, 15, 1])

print("$\sigma$ = ", popt_gauss[-1])

# Generate the fitted gaussian
gauss_fit = gaussian(x_fit, *popt_gauss)

plt.plot(x_fit, gauss_toep, label = r'Retrieved gaussian, $\sigma$ = {:.3f}'.format(sigma_gaussian))
plt.plot(x_fit, gauss_fit, label = r'Fitted retrieved, $\sigma$ = {:.3f}'.format(popt_gauss[-1]))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Input and output sigmoids (the orange is the convolution of the blue and a gaussian)]

[image: In blue the output of the toeplitz and Least square method, orange the fit of the gaussian, we have a 2/3 difference between the original gaussian (used for the convolution)]

Comment: I’m sorry, but isn’t this the same question you’ve asked  here? [Deconvolution using Toeplitz matrices](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/88958/deconvolution-using-toeplitz-matrices)

Comment: Yes it is but the question has been closed and my problem hasn’t been résolved..

Comment: If it has been closed, it’s for a reason. There’s no point re-asking the same exact question, it will be closed again. If you feel that it doesn’t deserve to be, you should see with the moderators why that’s so, and maybe they’ll re-open it.

Comment: It has been closed for the older version of my post. I changed it with the new findings i Had but since I had no news from the moderators so I asked with a New question. I could close the older one if needed.